# I want to remove text from a file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, parsing

Here is my code:

```
<?php include 'parser.php'; 
$api = $_GET['api']; 
$file = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
echo $file; 
?>
```

And this returns

```
Example text: 111.111.111.111
```

How can I remove Example text and only show the 111.111.111.111?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have every time the same return you can use `str_replace` or you can use `explode` and explode your string with the `:`. For example:

```
<?php include 'parser.php'; 
$api = $_GET['api']; 
$file = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
$res = explode(':',$file); 
echo $res[1];
?>
```

or with `str_replace`:

```
<?php include 'parser.php'; 
$api = $_GET['api']; 
$file = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
echo str_replace('Example text: ', '', $file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the file has in it is this text then you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = $file;
$newString = str_replace('Example text: ', '', $string);
echo $newString;
```